# Toggle between search engines in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, search-engines, duckduckgo

How can I easily toggle between DuckDuckGo and Google in the omnibox?

Is there a way to achieve it? Any plugins, shortcuts or so? The problem narrows down to changing the default search engine of Google Chrome using a shortcut.

The point is that Google is far better for non-English searches and technical information while DuckDuckGo provides the awesome [bangs!](https://duckduckgo.com/bang) feature. It would be great if I could easily switch between them whenever I need.

---

#### Clarification

When I use DuckDuckGo I can easily switch to Google by appending `!g` to my query. What I want is to be able to easily switch to Google, search multiple times without appending `!g` every time and then switch back to DDG.

Also, I use `!s` pretty often to switch to [StartPage](https://www.startpage.com) as they seem to aggregate results from Google.

Answer (score 44):

One way you can quickly toggle to a different search engine is by editing the `Keyword` for it in your list. With this approach you don't need to change your default search engine.

---

1. Right click on your Omnibar and click `Edit search engines...`

[image: Edit Search Engines]

2. Look for the `DuckDuckGo` entry and select it
3. The middle column enter a short and memorable keyword, like `du` for instance

[image: DuckDuckGo Entry]

4. Click `Done` to close the modal window

In the Omnibar, you can now just type `du` + <kbd>Space</kbd> on your keyboard to toggle `DuckDuckGo`. Then, just type a search term and off you go.

Here's how it looks in action

[image: DuckDuckGo Search]

---

If `DuckDuckGo` does not exist in your list of search engines, you can easily add it.

1. Right click on your Omnibar and click `Edit search engines...`
2. Scroll to the bottom of the `Other search engines` section and look for `Add a new search engine`
3. Enter `DuckDuckGo` for the search engine name, `du` (or other) for the keyword, and `https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%s&t=canonical` for the URL
4. Click `Done` to close the modal window

Comment: Thank you. It is not what I am looking for however. When I use DuckDuckGo I can easily switch to Google by appending `!g` to my query. What I want is to be able to easily switch to Google, search multiple times without appending `!g` everytime and then switch back to DDG.

Nice tutorial though, I'm sure it might be helpful for someone else.

Comment: Thanks. Coming from IE, I'm used to typing `?blah` and double clicking the search provider. Typing just the keyword was the bit I missed!

Answer (score 3):

I hope this won't be too late and would be a little helpful to you.

[Big Search (Github repo)](https://github.com/garywill/BigSearch) is an extension for Chrome+Firefox to do multiple search.

[image: screenshot]

- To switch a search engine: Select the search box text. Then use selected text (single-line or multi-line) as search term via context menu

  > - On Chrome, after clicking context menu item, click the icon on toolbar (or use keyboard shortcut) (sorry this may be a little tricky for your "**toggle between search engines**", because of a [defect of Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54189283/chrome-extension-open-popup-from-contentscript-file#comment95207111_54189283) currently. No such tricky on Firefox, popup automatically show)

  - Or, just do continuous search by clicking multiple buttons on popup, then multiple search result tabs are open.
- Besides using context menu, keyboard shortcuts for 1. Open popup. 2. Set selected text as search term (then use open popup).

Answer (score 2):

I was in search for the same thing, but couldn't find something as easy as I wanted, so I just developed an easy bookmark hack to do this!

First, just create a bookmark in your bookmarks bar, then **edit the URL of the bookmark**, and put in the following code, which will automatically translate any Duck Duck Go search into a Google search  (you can change the name of the bookmark to anything you want):

```
javascript:location.href="https://google.com/search"+location.search
```

Whenever you want to change a Duck Duck Go search into a Google search, just click the bookmark. The same can be done for other search engines as well, such as Yahoo, Brave, etc., just by changing the URL part of the link.

For example, if you want to change a Google search into a Duck Duck Go search, just use another bookmark with this link:

```
javascript:location.href="https://duckduckgo.com/"+location.search
```

If you want to switch to Brave search, just paste this into a bookmark:

```
javascript:location.href="https://search.brave.com/search"+location.search
```

For Yahoo:

```
javascript:location.href="https://search.yahoo.com/search"+location.search
```

For Bing use:

```
javascript:location.href="https://bing.com/search"+location.search
```

To keep my bookmark bar tidy, I just named each of the bookmarks as a single letter (B for Brave, G for Google, M for Microsoft Bing, etc.). Hope all this is helpful to someone! Cheers!

Comment: Now it would be powerful, if I could trigger this bookmark with a shortcut.

Comment: You probably could with ScriptKit https://www.scriptkit.com/

Answer (score 2):

try this Chrome extension -- LeapSearch
It can make you switch between different search engine efficiently.

[LeapSearch | ChromeWebStore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/leapsearch/lapaieaegaclofackbjhjhbhfiplcgki/related)

[LeapSearch snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msZuK.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

there are extensions. One particular is called 'search centre' you literally click on the toolbar, type your query and select which search engine you are using [you have to go and find the ones you want for instance I set imdb as one by going to imdb and right clicking the search box and selecting 'add to search centre']

I wish there was one where it just added a little drop box to the omnibox so you could type your query then choose which engine to use. you can do that in firefox but chrome doesn't seem to have it..

I hope this helps but I know it's not quite what you wanted but it's better than having to mess around with keywords and stuff every time.

Comment: Still, it does not toggle search engines. It offers me a drop-down list instead. It is not what I am looking for. Thanks anyway :)